# FiPy not working

Tags: python, pde, fipy

After a fresh installation of FiPy on a Mac (OS X 10.10.2 and Python 2.7.6) I tried some example from the documentation, but they didn't work. So I tested FiPy using the built-in test routine (typing "fipy.test()" from the python shell) but after a long list of good doctests I got this log, with two failures:
https://gist.github.com/alfrenardi/3b1ad5ff814077b18882

I tried on a fresh LTS Ubuntu installation too, but I got the same problem. There is any workaround? In my opinion this looks like a issue of the FiPy module, not of the platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are some problems with the tests. I made a request to the developers with a patch. I consider this question solved.

Answer (score 1):

The two tests that are failing

```
print type(numerix.array([1.0, 2.0]) * PhysicalField([1.0, 2.0])) is type(numerix.array(1))
```

and

```
C = CellVariable(mesh=mesh) * (A * B)
```

are edge cases that are very unlikely to interfere with most FiPy use cases. The warnings such as

```
Skipped 105 doctest examples because `gmsh` cannot be found on the $PATH
```

only matter if you plan to use some feature that those libraries provide.

As a very basic test of your installation (above and beyond the test suite), try and run the 1D diffusion problem outlined in the [1D diffusion example](http://www.ctcms.nist.gov/fipy/examples/diffusion/generated/examples.diffusion.mesh1D.html) and check that something sensible is plotted to the screen.

Comment: Simple examples like the one you pointed work (on Ubuntu), but I have to solve an electrostatic 3D problem and I do not know if I'll have to use that "special edge" cases or I will not. Plus, I suspect that a module which cannot pass its own tests after a fresh installation is not reliable. Thanks for your answer, but if I can't solve this issue in few weeks I'll look for another python library.

Comment: Anyways, do you think the two tests fail because of a missing library or that it is a problem of FiPy? I used the "master" version on GitHub, I suppose it should be the most stable.

Comment: I'm not sure why the tests are failing without debugging in this instance. Often FiPy tests fail because the underlying libraries change in some way and the FiPy developers fail to keep up. In my own research, I rarely have a version of FiPy with all the tests passing, just due to the complexity of keeping up with changes in the underlying dependencies.

Comment: Actually, the problems were caused by incoherent tests inside FiPy, not by external libraries (if you are interested, you can find a pull request on the GitHub page of the project). Anyways, it is better to have wrongly written tests than an actual bug in the code.